# How do i link a html drop down menu to php xpath query to xml file?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following php/ xpath query. I cant seem to find the logic to link this script to a html page /client side web page with a search box for user to choose what they want to see from the xml file. I can of course make a select drop down with a search button but am struggling to  link it all up.

The php code below searches the xml file and picks out elements whose prices are between £100k and £200k..

```
<div>
<label for="xsltsearch">Choose a Price:</label>


    <select id="xsltsearch">
      <option value="">Price To</option>
      <option value="">£100,000</option>
      <option value="">£200,000</option>
      <option value="">£300,000</option>
      <option value="">£400,000</option>
    </select>


    <select>
      <option value="">Price From</option>
      <option value="">£100,000</option>
      <option value="">£200,000</option>
      <option value="">£300,000</option>
      <option value="">£400,000</option>
    </select>
    <form method="post" action="example.xml">
      <input name="search" type="text" class="input" value="" /> 
       <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</html>


  <?php 

    $xml =  simplexml_load_file('xml_files/example.xml') or die("can not find it");

    $a = "100000.00";
    $b = "200000.00";



    $result = $xml->xpath("//property[(numeric_price> '" . $a . "'  ) and (numeric_price< '" . $b . "')     ]/numeric_price ");


       while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {

        echo  'Asking Price: ',$node,"\n"  ;

    }


    ?>
```

Comment: You wan't to find every `property` tag has `numeric_price` property with special value from xml file?

Comment: when will people STOP using the horrendous simple xml?? Use the DOM classes!

Comment: Interesting comment delboy. i can use dom to display what i need. this doesnt answer my question. any chance of a solution of how you would go about linking web page to my xml fille so user can query it against 2 conditions?

Answer (score 0):

```
Maybe this question was to simple to answer on here. 
I created 

In the drop down menu 1    
<select name="price"> 
In the drop down menu 2    
<select name="prices"> 

i then posted the form like you would any other php script and

Created a variable for the values of 'price' and 'prices' which insert the chosen user £values selected from the drop down menu. 

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
$a = $_POST['price'];
$b = $_POST['prices'];

i then queried the xml file 

$result = $xml->property->xpath("//property[(numeric_price> '" . $a . "'  ) and (numeric_price< '" . $b . "')   ]  ");
```

and sort the data as you want

```
usort($result, function ($a, $b) { return (int) $a->numeric_price - (int) $b->numeric_price; });

//function to sort price high to low.
usort($result, function ($a, $b) { return (int) $b->numeric_price - (int) $a->numeric_price; });

foreach ($result as $elements){
```

you can then echo out the elements of the xml file that you need to display back to the user. The foreach loop will select every product that matches the price query  :

```
echo 'Asking Price:',$elements->numeric_price."  / " ;"\n";
echo 'Tenure:', $elements->tenure." / "; "\n";
echo 'Address:'." ", $elements->advert_heading; "\n";
```